# JAVA - How to access variables inside a FOR loop, from outside the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My code is to add RSS feeds to a list - and the code originally was only to pull one feed from the first position in a list, and add this object to another list.

This was the original code:

```
public static List<Feed> getFeedsFromXml(String xml) {
      Pattern feedPattern = Pattern.compile("<feed>\\s*<name>\\s*([^<]*)</name>\\s*<uri>\\s*([^<]*)</uri>\\s*</feed>");


      Matcher feedMatch = feedPattern.matcher(xml);
      while (feedMatch.find()) {
          String feedName = feedMatch.group(1);
          String feedURI = feedMatch.group(2);
          feeds.add(new Feed(feedName, feedURI));
      }

      return feeds;
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addXmlFeed() throws IOException
{
    int i = 0;
    String stringXml = "<feed><name>SMH Top Headlines</name><uri>http://feeds.smh.com.au/rssheadlines/top.xml</uri></feed><feed><name>UTS Library News</name>";
    getFeedsFromXml(stringXml);
    Feed f = (Feed) feeds.get(0);
    feedList.add(f);
    String handler = "You have successfully added: \n"; 
    String xmlStringReply = "" + f + "\n";

    feedList.save(feedFile);
    return handler + xmlStringReply;

}
```

Everything was going well, and then I decided to implement a for loop for handling the adding of more than one feed to the list, and I tried the following (only the code for the second method in question):

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addXmlFeed() throws IOException
{
    int i = 0;
    String stringXml = "<feed><name>SMH Top Headlines</name><uri>http://feeds.smh.com.au/rssheadlines/top.xml</uri></feed><feed><name>UTS Library News</name>";
    getFeedsFromXml(stringXml);
    for (Feed feed: feeds)
    {
        Feed f = (Feed) feeds.get(i++);
        feedList.add(f);
        String handler = "You have successfully added: \n"; 
        String xmlStringReply = "" + f + "\n";
    }

    feedList.save(feedFile);
    return handler + xmlStringReply;

}
```

Now I'm sure this is a basic problem, but now in the line:

```
    return handler + xmlStringReply;
```

`handler` and `xmlStringReply` cannot be resolved to a variable as they are within the FOR LOOP.

Is there any easy way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scope of those 2 variables is limited to the for loop. To access them outside the loop, you need to increase their scope by declaring them before the loop:

```
String handler = ""; 
String xmlStringReply = "";
for (Feed f: feeds) {
    feedList.add(f);
    handler = "You have successfully added: \n"; 
    xmlStringReply = "" + f + "\n";
}

feedList.save(feedFile);
return handler + xmlStringReply;
```

Also, your current code overwrites the value of your strings at each loop, whereas you probably meant to concatenate the values. In that case, you could use a StringBuilder instead of string concatenation:

```
StringBuilder xmlStringReply = new StringBuilder("You have successfully added: \n");
for (Feed f: feeds) {
    feedList.add(f);
    xmlStringReply.append(f + "\n");
}

feedList.save(feedFile);
return xmlStringReply.toString();
```

Comment: Note that you might not want to overwrite the values, but append some information to the Strings instead.

Comment: @StefanNeubert Yes good point - I had missed the absence of `+`.

Comment: @assylias thank you also for a clear & concise response, both of the upper responses were very helpful, although I have accepted yours as it explains in more detail, which was extremely useful. All the best!

Comment: @assylias - It looks like we have a serial downvoter, I am downvoted too.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Yes it seems... Whatever! I +1'ed you FWIW ;-)

Comment: What do you think of the responses from Orabig and Adeel Ansari below?
Is this also correct?

Comment: @PetarMinchev It was maybe because we did not remove the `feed.get(i++)` thing.

Comment: @assylias - Thanks, I have upvoted you too:) Lol, I did not see the `i++` at all.

Comment: @AlexM Yes and Orabig makes a good point - I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because, now they became out of scope.

Beside the original error -- you can easily fix that using other suggestions, I would like to suggest that you should not make `feeds` as instance variable. I can see your method `getFeedsFromXml()` is returning the list. So, I think it would have been better if you define that variable inside that method. And then, call the method like,

```
List<Feed> feeds = getFeedsFromXml(stringXml);
```

Or in case, this doesn't give you the desired behaviour, then you should rename the method to something, `loadFeedsFromXml()`. **Making that as instance variable may result in threading issues**.

Now, trying to improve on your looping,

```
StringBuilder xmlStringReply = new StringBuilder("You have successfully added: \n");
for (Feed feed: feeds) {
    feedList.add(feed);
    xmlStringReply.append(f + "\n");
}

feedList.save(feedFile);
return xmlStringReply.toString();
```

Moreover, I found that your `feedList` is also a instance variable. And this again can cause threading issues, as it doesn't sound immutable or stateless. Synchronising the methods will give you performance issues. See if you can make it local to this method. **A rule of thumb is to keep variable scope as narrow as possible**.

Comment: Hey, folks. What's wrong with this answer? I think you folks can't wait.

Comment: I downvoted it because the original answer didn't make sense. I've removed the downvote now.

Comment: @Nick: To me the original answer made a lot of sense, but yes may not be very clear for the beginner. "Because, now they became out of scope", was my original answer. Anyway, thanks for revoking the negative cast.

Answer (score 2):

You need to accumulate the result into a variable. I am using `StringBuilder` because it makes string concatenation efficient.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addXmlFeed() throws IOException
{
    String stringXml = "<feed><name>SMH Top Headlines</name><uri>http://feeds.smh.com.au/rssheadlines/top.xml</uri></feed><feed><name>UTS Library News</name>";
    getFeedsFromXml(stringXml);

    StringBuilder replyBuilder = new StringBuilder("You have successfully added: \n");
    for (Feed feed : feeds)
    {
        feedList.add(feed);

        String xmlStringReply = feed  + "\n";
        reployBuilder.append(xmlStringReply); 
    }

    feedList.save(feedFile);
    return replyBuilder.toString();    
}
```

Comment: @Peter Minchev, excellent, very helpful thankyou. Just one question, in your code, I assume the String variable "xmlStringReply" should be declared outside of the FOR loop as well as String variable "Handler".
Is this correct?

Comment: @AlexM No it does not have to because it is only use within the loop.

Comment: @AlexM - `Handler` should be outside, but `xmlStringReply` there is no need.

Answer (score 2):

The question **you** need to answer is "what do I want to return if I add several feeds ?".

Maybe you'd like to return `"You have successfully added : feed1 feed2 feed3\n"`

In that case, the code is :

```
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder( "You have successfully added: ");
            for (Feed feed: feeds)
                {
                    feedList.add(feed);
                    response.append(f.toString()).append(" ");
                }
            feedList.save(feedFile);
            return response.toString();
```

---

**By the way**, your `feed`and `f`variables are just the same and redondant !

Don't write :

```
int i = 0;    
for (Feed feed: feeds)
{
    Feed f = (Feed) feeds.get(i++);
    feedList.add(f);
}
```

but

```
for (Feed feed: feeds)
{
    feedList.add(feed);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, the reason it was coded as the prior, was that initially, the functional requirement was that I only pull the FIRST feed from the list, and add it, and now the next functional requirement was to then add a mechanism for accepting multiple feeds.

I will investigate your response.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to view scope like this:

```
 { //This is a constructor

  int i;

} // This is a deconstructor
```

anything that is created / instantiated between the curlies only lives inside the curlies. Whenever your working with variables and loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

 //some code here
 } // after this curly i is no longer in scope or accessible.
```